# fastest way to load images in python for processing

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to load more than 10000 images in my 8gb ram in the form of numpy arrays.So far I have tried cv2.imread,keras.preprocessing.image.load_image,pil,imageio,scipy.I want to do it the fastest way possible but I can't figure out which on is it.

Comment: Can you use https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fastest ways is to get your multiprocessors to do your job in Parallel. It brings multiple processors to work on your tasks at the same time when concurrent running isn't an issue. Now the example below is just a simple sketch of how it might look, you can practice with small functions and then integrate them with your own code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process
    #this is the function to be parallelized
    def image_load_here(image_path):
        pass 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Start the multiprocesses and provide your dataset.
    p = Process(target=image_load_here,['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4'])
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Feel free to write, ill try to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from keras.preprocessing import image


    def batch_data_generator(data, indexes):
        #indexes is a sub array of index from the data
        X = np.zeros((len(indexes), config.IMG_INPUT_SHAPE[0], config.IMG_INPUT_SHAPE[1], config.IMG_INPUT_SHAPE[2]))
        Y = np.zeros((len(indexes), len(label_mapping)))
        i = 0
        for idx in indexes:
            image_id = data['X'][idx]
            filename = os.path.join('images', str(image_id) + '.jpg')
            img = image.load_img(filename, target_size=(300, 300))
            X[i] = np.array(img, dtype='float32')
            label_id = label_mapping[data['Y'][idx]]
            Y[i][label_id] = 1
            i += 1
        # subtract mean and normalize
        for depth in range(3):
            X[:, :, :, depth] = (X[:, :, :, depth] - np.mean(X[:, :, :, depth])) / 255
        return X, Y
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `keras` library in order to create a `deep learning` model, I suggest you to use `image` class from `keras.preprocessing` package.

`image` class provides a method `img_to_array` which returns already a `numpy` array.

Also, it uses `NumPy - Numpy` internally for all its `array` manipulations/computations.

```
train_image = image.load_img(path, target_size = (height, width)) 
train_image = image.img_to_array(train_image)
```

Comment: actually I am using something similar where instead of img_to_array I use np.asarray(train_image) and it's slightly faster.

Comment: @dhrumilbarot, you can accept my answer if helps you.