# faster way to load images?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm a Python novice but have a decent amount of experience in other languages. I'm using this loop to load in a directory of images for some machine learning, which is why I convert them to numpy arrays. It's very slow, so I must be doing something wrong!

My current code:

```
def load_images(src):
  
  files = []  # accept multiple extensions
  for ext in ('*.gif', '*.png', '*.PNG', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.JPG', '*.JPEG'):
    files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(src, ext)))

  images = []
  for each in files:
    print(each)
    img = PIL.Image.open(each)
    img_array = np.asarray(img)
    images.append(img_array)

  return images

# need to convert from list to numpy array
train_images = np.asarray(load_images(READY_IMAGES))
```

Comment: if they're all the same size, i wouldn't convert to a numpy array until the very end.

Comment: also, you _might_ need to close the `img` object

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your insight! How do I convert to a numpy array at the end? My confusion is: I don't want to end up with a numpy array containing images, but rather a numpy array containing numpy arrays. But perhaps Python will do this automagically?

Comment: Sorry, I was switching up my libraries. You probably don't need to convert your final list of images to an array. A list of arrays is really no different than a 1-D array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
    #this is the function to be parallelised
    def image_load_here(image_path):
        pass 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Start the multiprocesses and provide your dataset.
    p = Process(target=image_load_here,['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4'])
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Original Code link : [fastest way to load images in python for processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233954/fastest-way-to-load-images-in-python-for-processing)

Extra Refer

1. [Fastest image reader? Four ways to open a Satellite image in Python](http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/fastest-image-python/)
2. [Efficient image loading](https://www.learnopencv.com/efficient-image-loading/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using machine learning with keras/tensorflow you can use a generator to really speed up your loading process and it will consume memory on the go, thereby conserving your RAM for other uses.
[Here](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720) is an excellent article on the function. You can visit the  [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)too.